# Can Blender show edges of lo-res mesh on hi-res mesh when editing subdiv surface?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm wondering if Blender implements a feature that Maya has.  Mainly, if you're editing a mesh with a subdiv modifier, is there any way to have the lines of the lo-res mesh drawn directly on the model?

Here's a screen shot from Maya:

[image]

This is what I'm able to do in Blender.  The lo-res mesh is next to the model instead of projected onto it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the fourth icon next to the subdivision surface name (Triangular Polygon).

The tooltip is **Adjust edit cage to modifier result**.

[image]

Note that while you will be seeing a displaced vertice, the editing operation still act on the original vertices with their respective locations.